# Loosing Foreign Key when querying In different Controllers/Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, foreign-keys

I have a Model Rental in my ASP.Net 4.5 MVC Project. Rental has 2 foreign keys ProfileId(Profile Model) & ItemId(Item Model). Both are set properly when the Rental record is created.

In Controller #1 if i run:

```
var rentals = GetRentals(6);

      public IQueryable<Rental> GetRentals(int parent)
      {
          return db.Rentals.Where(t => t.ProfileId.Equals(parent));
      }
var rentalArray = rentals.ToArray();
```

rentalArray has the proper item id and FK index, allowing me to run  rentalArray[i].Item.Name [Good Response Pic from Code Above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU3Xe.png)

Now In controller #2 if i run

```
  var rentals = GetRentals(6);

      public IQueryable<Rental> GetRentals(int parent)
      {
          return db.Rentals.Where(t => t.ProfileId.Equals(parent));
      }
var rentalArray = rentals.ToArray();
```

In this query i loose the item FK property of the Rental, though the ItemId is still coming in properly. I am unable to run rentalArray[i].Item.Name as Item is null.

Both are the same database record, Im just querying in a different Controller/Method. [Picture of bad response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHupH.png)

I cannot determine why Rental.Item property comes in null on the second query? [Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV6aB.png)

Rental Model:

```
public class Rental
{
    public int RentalId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
    public bool? Accepted { get; set; }
    public bool? Complete { get; set; }
    public DateTime BeginRental { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndRental { get; set; }
    public int ChargeAmount { get; set; }
    public bool Canceled { get; set; }
    public string ChargeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the very same method and access it one time using `itemId` and `profileId`? This seems odd...

Comment: Hmm...they were in separate controllers but now ive tested in the same controller and its giving the same result of Item coming in null even when querying by same, so it appears to be issue with the controller/method?

Comment: My assumption is that you have other IDs than expected - but I can't tell you for sure. Like I said: `profileID` and `itemID` are likely not the same or just the same by chance.

Comment: i ran the first function in both controllers now, it returns the null Item in the second controller/method, though returns the right record. The controllers return different VMS from each other though both have the same properties for rentals. Going to update question to better reflect.

Comment: Have you noticed that in your bad picture you have `LibLob.Models.Profile` instead of a reference to an `System.Data.Entity` object?
You said your `DBContext` was the same?

Comment: That was the answer, thanks bash.d.

Comment: Glad to hear! Party on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use include method

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

and you can use it like this:-

```
return db.Rentals.include(tt => tt.Profile).include(ttt => ttt.Item).Where(t => t.ProfileId.Equals(parent));
```

Comment: A far better solution than my quick fix thank you! By using two db contexts it gave me error with needing all threads available to evaluate FK objets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bash.d for finding issue.

> Have you noticed that in your bad picture you have
>   LibLob.Models.Profile instead of a reference to an System.Data.Entity
>   object? You said your DBContext was the same?

Controller #1 was using a ApplicationDBContext while controller#2 was using ProxylessApplicationDbContext, resulting in Rental.Item appearing but being null in controller #2. Fixed by adding a second dbcontext and using that only for method to retrieve rentals.